# Double 301 redirection SSL with long waiting time

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

Reading a lot of my problem on this website, however I can't find my problem in my .htaccess file. Hopefully someone can tell me what the problem is and how I can improve this.

Let me first start with the problem. My problem is, that when I type in example.com in my webbrowser, the following redirections will take place:

Example.com (301)-> https://example.com (301)-> https://www.example.com (200).
-> This is due to Wordpress configuration with www.

Already downloaded ReallySimpleSSL plugin, but still I have these 3 steps. Posting my htaccess, because I think that super cache can also be part of my problem.

Hopefully someone can give me some advice! Thank you in advance.

```
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#If you serve pages from behind a proxy you may want to change 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on' to something more sensible
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|_icl_current_language|_icl_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|_icl_current_language|_icl_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e|wp-postpass_).*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz" [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|_icl_current_language|_icl_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e|wp-postpass_).*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html" [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|_icl_current_language|_icl_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e|wp-postpass_).*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WPSuperCache
    
    
    # BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[4.0.6]
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
    # END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
    
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress
```

Should I also post header information from the speedtest website if necessary?

Thank you in advance for helping me. Already consultated my hosting company, but they doesn't see the problem aswell.

Comment: SSL redirects should always happen before anything else, but here you got the supercache rules before. If those plugins don’t offer a way to manipulate in which order they write their stuff into the .htaccess, then your best bet is probably to not use the ReallySimpleSSL plugin, but copy&paste that section at the start manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Deleted the plugin and places this code above: Deleted all the caches and still have the problem: http://example.com -> https://example.com -> https://www.example.com. `#HTTPS Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#END HTTPS Rewrite.` Using Varnish, could that be that problem?